# I have a simple script that ask for my pass when it shouldn't

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have this simple script /home/myuser/startup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# sin le pongo -x al final va tirando por pantalla todo lo que hace

echo "Finding PIDs of mysql processes..."
mysql_pid=$(sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 'mysql' | awk 'NR==1{print $2}')

echo "Check if 'mysql_pid' is not empty"
if [ -n "$mysql_pid" ]; then
  echo "MySQL PID found: $mysql_pid"
  sudo kill "$mysql_pid"
  echo "MySQL process killed."
else
  echo "MySQL process not found."
fi

echo "Launching Docker Desktop..."
systemctl --user start docker-desktop
```

I don't want to manually enter the passwoird everytime I run it (on every boot I run `./startup.sh`), so I added this file /etc/sudoers.d/startup with this line:

```
myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/myuser/startup.sh
```

but everytime I run the script it keeps asking me for my password, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: How do you run the script? And why are you using `lsof` instead of just `ps aux | awk '$1=="mysql"{print $2}'`? `lsof` needs root, so that seems to be complicating things needlessly. Actually, what is this script doing? If you just want to kill mysql if it is running, you can just do `killall mysql`, is the script even needed?

Comment: @terdon everytime i boot i have to kill mysql before starting the docker containters i need to work, so that's my "every day rutine", and the PID of the mysql process changes on every boot.... so that's what it basically does, find the PID of the mysql processes and kill it, and then launch docker desktop

Comment: OK, then all you need is `killall mysql; systemctl --user start docker-desktop`, nothing else. But, again, how are you running the script? Manually or automatically? Are you running it as your user or with `sudo script.sh`?

Comment: I was running it mannually: `./startup.sh` 
I'll try: `killall mysql; systemctl --user start docker-desktop`
Thanks!

Comment: Please add this to your question. That is the problem: you have given yourself permission to run the script without a password, but you are not running it with sudo so the whole exercise is pointless.

Comment: @terdon quiestion edited. Now I get it, i guess i'd run the command with ```sudo -/startup.sh``` enter the pass there and the script will run

Comment: Exactly, but you wouldn't even enter the pass, since you have it in sudoers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sudoers` line allows you to run

```
sudo /home/myuser/startup.sh
```

without entering a password, but not

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n
```

or

```
sudo kill
```

which are the commands your script actually runs.
So `sudo` duly asks for a password for these.

In general, if you use `sudo` within a script you should use the `-n` or `--non-interactive` option to make sure it won't ask for a password but instead fail with an appropriate error message if not permitted to proceed without one, which would have helped you pinpoint the problem.

Your `lsof` command line, including the `grep` and `awk` invocations, can be replaced by `pgrep mysql` which doesn't need root permissions, obviating the need for a `sudoers` entry. You'll still need one for the `kill` command, though, which is a pretty powerful command to give that kind of blanket permission for.

As an alternative, drop all `sudo` invocations from your script, and instead run the entire script as `root` with

```
sudo /home/myuser/startup.sh
```

as allowed by your `sudoers` line.
You should still replace `lsof` by `pgrep` as described above because it is more robust, more efficient, and closer to the principle of least privilege.